# Typesafe Config: best pattern for overriding substitutions in later settings?

Tags: typesafe-stack, typesafe-config

Ok, I have tried the following and it's not producing the effect that I'd have wished for.  I have a `reference.conf` specifying filesystem locations relative to a prefix, which looks somewhat like this:

```
// reference.conf
myapp {
    // The dummy path makes the error message easy to diagnose
    s3.prefix = "s3://environment/variable/S3_PREFIX/missing"
    s3.prefix = ${?S3_PREFIX}

    file1 = ${myapp.s3.prefix}"/file1.csv"
    file2 = ${myapp.s3.prefix}"/file2.csv"
    // ...
}
```

And then I supply an `application.conf` file that looks more or less like this:

```
// application.conf
myapp.s3.prefix = "s3://some-bucket/some/path/to/the/files"
myapp.file2 = "s3://some-other-bucket/some/path/file2.csv"
```

Now, when my application does a `ConfigFactory.load()`, from :

1. Parse the `reference.conf` file, perform the substitutions, and generate a `Config` object where:

   - `myapp.s3.prefix = "/environment/variable/S3_PREFIX/missing"`
   - `myapp.file1 = "/environment/variable/S3_PREFIX/missing/file1.csv"`
   - `myapp.file2 = "/environment/variable/S3_PREFIX/missing/file2.csv"`.
2. Parse the `application.conf` file and generate a `Config` object where:

   - `library.prefix = "/some/path/to/the/files"`
   - `myapp.file2 = "s3://some-other-bucket/some/path/file2.csv"`.
3. Merge the two objects, with the `reference.conf` object as fallback.  The resulting `Config` object therefore has:

   - `library.prefix = "s3://some-bucket/some/path/to/the/files"` (as in `application.conf`)
   - `library.file1 = "s3://environment/variable/S3_PREFIX/missing/file1.csv"` (as in `reference.conf`).
   - `library.file2 = "s3://some-other-bucket/some/path/file2.csv"` (as in `application.conf`).

But as you may have guessed from my example, what I'm trying to do is have the `reference.conf` specify default paths *relative* to a root directory, and allow any mix of **both** of these:

1. Override the default root directory from the `application.conf`, so that the default relative paths from the `reference.conf` are looked up from there.
2. Override the path for any individual file in the `application.conf`, so the application can use a path not in the root directory.

The only thing I've been able to come up with so far is this:

```
// reference.conf
myapp {
    // The dummy path makes the error message easy to diagnose
    s3.prefix = "s3:/environment/variable/S3_PREFIX/missing"
    s3.prefix = ${?S3_PREFIX}

    file1 = "file1.csv"
    file2 = "file2.csv"
    // ...
}

// application.conf
myapp.s3.prefix = "s3://some-bucket/some/path/to/the/files"
myapp.file2 = "s3://some-other-bucket/some/path/file2.csv"


// The Java code for using the config must append prefix and file location,
// and needs to have smarts about relative vs. absolute paths.

final Config CONF = ConfigFactory.load();

String getS3URLFor(String file) {
    String root = CONF.getString("myapp.s3.prefix");
    String path = CONF.getString("myapp." + file);
    return relativeVsAbsoluteSensitiveMerge(root, path);
}

String relativeVsAbsoluteSensitiveMerge(String root, String path) {
    if (isAbsoluteReference(path)) {
        return path; 
    } else {
        return root + "/" + path;
    }
}

boolean isAbsoluteReference(String path) {
   // ...
}
```

I don't really like this solution.  Can anybody think of something better?

Answer (score 2):

You can parse first and then resolve:

```
ConfigFactory.parseResources(s"file.conf")
  .withValue("myKey", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef("newValue"))
  .resolve()
```